# I need select and catch the id of button(touchable opacity) selected

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-native, expo

I need to select a button and get its specific id to delete it. However, after executing the first time, the id of the excluded one is kept and not the other one selected.

I need a way to get the id of my selected item

```
<View>

type BookProps = {
    id: string;
    name: string;
    description: string;
    updatedAt: string;
    authorId: string;
  }
  
const [books, setBooks] = useState<BookProps[] | []>([])

{books.map((book, index) => <BookItem key={index} bookId={book.id} name={book.name} description={book.description} updatedAt={book.updatedAt} />)}
</View>
```

the component is here:

```
export default function BookItem({ name, description, bookId, updatedAt}: BookProps) {

function deleteItem(bookId: string){

}

return(
<TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteItem} >
        <Text>{name}</Text>
        <Text>{description}</Text>
        <Text>{updatedAt}</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
)}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass an *onDelete* function from the parent to remove an item from the *books* state.

```
const ParentComponent = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState<BookProps[] | []>([])

  const handleDeleteBook = (bookId: string) => {
    setBooks(books.filter(book => book.id !== bookId));
  }

  return (
    <View>
      {books.map((book, index) => (
        <BookItem
          key={index}
          bookId={book.id}
          name={book.name}
          description={book.description}
          updatedAt={book.updatedAt}
          onDelete={handleDeleteBook}
        />
      ))}
    </View>
  );
}

type BookItemProps = BookProps & {
  onDelete: (bookId: string) => void;
}

export default function BookItem({ name, description, id, updatedAt, onDelete }: BookItemProps) {

  const deleteItem = () => {
    onDelete(id);
  }


  return (
    <TouchableOpacity onPress={deleteItem}>
      <Text>{name}</Text>
      <Text>{description}</Text>
      <Text>{updatedAt}</Text>
    </TouchableOpacity>
  )
}
```